# Problem with Python class definition and creating an object

Tags: python, class, object, attributes, parameter-passing

I am doing an assignment for class where I have to create a "Car" class and then create an object of the class and call the methods.

The class is to have 3 data attributes - __year_model and __make are supposed to be accepted as arguments and the attribute __speed is to be set to 0.

I have this code:

```
class Car:

    def __int__(self, year_model, make):
        self.__year_model = year_model
        self.__make = make
        self.__speed = 0

    def accelerate(self):
        self.__speed += 5

    def brake(self):
        self.__speed - + 5

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed


def main():
    my_car = Car("2022 Trailblazer", "Chevy")

    for i in range(5):
        my_car.accelerate()
        print(my_car.get_speed())

    for i in range(5):
        my_car.brake()
        print(my_car.get_speed())
```

I get a few errors with this code. First, in the brake method - the error says "statement seems to have no effect." When I create the object in the main function, I get the error "unexpected argument" for both "2022 Trailblazer" and "Chevy". Finally, I am not getting any output when I run the code - I should be seeing the printouts for the speed.

How can I fix these problems?

Comment: It should be `__init__`, not `__int__`

Comment: You should also have a look at `self.__speed - + 5`

Comment: `self.__speed - + 5` is equivalent to writing `self.__speed - 5`. A value is created, but nothing is modified. The method is useless. Python's warning is telling you this.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to track down problems before asking. One important technique is to use debug traces to make sure that methods are getting called. "Finally, I am not getting any output when I run the code - I should be seeing the printouts for the speed" Well, yes; once there is an uncaught exception, no more of the program can run.

Comment: "I have worked really hard searching for answers and am not sure what I am doing wrong" Did you try [copying and pasting the error message into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=TypeError%3A+Car()+takes+no+arguments)? "in the brake method - the error says "statement seems to have no effect."" This is not an actual error message - it is a warning from your IDE. It can [still be easily searched](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+statement+seems+to+have+no+effect), however. It's important to look at code closely. Think: what is `self.__speed - + 5` intended to do? Does that look right?

Comment: Finally: please keep in mind that this is *not a discussion forum or a debugging service*, and we generally are looking for **one, specific** question per post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you had a mistake in the **init** method, hence why your Class wasnt accepting any variables. Second of all, if you decide to put Class instantiation in a method, you need to return the variable, as well as assign the results of the main() function to one. Below is your fixed code, that seems to run as intended:

```
class Car:
    # constructor method is inIt not int
    def __init__(self, year_model, make):
        self.__year_model = year_model
        self.__make = make
        self.__speed = 0

    def accelerate(self):
        self.__speed += 5

    def brake(self):
        self.__speed -= 5

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed

# you need to return my_car from this function for it to work
def main():
    my_car = Car("2022 Trailblazer", "Chevy")
    return my_car

# Instantiating your function
my_car = main()

for i in range(5):
    my_car.accelerate()
    print(my_car.get_speed())

for i in range(5):
    my_car.brake()
    print(my_car.get_speed())
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also as people mentioned, to decrease a variable you need to use '-=' not '- +'.

Comment: the `main` method should encompass all of that, it just needs to be called, conventionally, in an `if __name__ == "__main__": ...` guard